# CallKit and Apple Watch interoperability

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, callkit

Along the news that came with the release of iOS 10 and WatchOS 3 there was **[CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/)**.

I tried the demo app provided by Apple (and shown in the WWDC) called [SpeakerBox](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017290) in my devices (iPhone 6s, iOS 10 <s>beta 5</s>; AppleWatch with WatchOS 3 <s>beta 5</s>) and I have a serious doubt:

Are the features provided by CallKit available only on iOS or, since it uses the OS call system, we will have Apple Watch call handling for free as well?

I tested with the demo app but in that case **I have the call ringing only on the phone**, that sounds to me very weird since CallKit should be a framework to simplify the integration with the OS call system.

Does anybody know how and if is possible to have the standard call handling in WatchOS (>3 of course) as well?

Comment: Face same issue. Have you find workaround yet?

Comment: Nope. Nothing new yet 